# How to get data from MongoDB with mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, command-line-interface

I am writing CLI in which user can get any collection from MongoDB by entering the name of this connection to the console.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://paito:-----mlab.com:22222/paito', { useNewUrlParser: true });

const getCollection = (collection) => {
    db.getCollection(collection)
        .exec((err, data) => {
            // assert.equal(null, err);
            console.info(data);
            console.info(`${data.length} matches`);
            db.close();
        })
};

module.exports = {
    getCollection
};
```

I need to get this data to the console. The actual error "TypeError: db.getCollection is not a function".

Comment: isnt it `db.collection(collectionName)` ?

Comment: I am passing the name of the collection to this function and this doesn't working

Comment: so you have `db.getCollection(collection)` but i think it was db.collection ? its not working? let me check docs